# What does \$x^*(t)=x(t)\$ mean in signals and systems?

Tags: signal, math-notation

I am often seeing this notation \$x^*(t)=x(t)\$ or similar but I cannot remember when I saw it the first time and I cannot find anywhere that explains the meaning of that notation. What does it mean?

Comment: \$x^*(t)\$ can also relate to a sampled signal, the \$*\$ is the means to distinguish it from a continuous-time waveform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\$x^*(t)\$ is the complex conjugate of \$x(t)\$

So, when \$x(t)\$ is defined as $$x(t)=a+bj$$ then $$x^*(t)=a-bj$$.

When $$x^*(t)=x(t)$$ it means

$$a+bj=a-bj$$

This is only true when \$b=0\$, so \$x(t)\$ has to be a real number.

Answer (score 1):

\$x^*\$ means the [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate), i.e. if \$x = a + jb\$, then \$x^* = (a + jb)^* = a -jb\$. So if \$x=x^*\$ obviously \$b\$ must be 0, i.e. then \$x\$ is real.

Answer (score 0):

it means that the signal is real-valued